error when sudo apt update: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 254B391D8CACCBF8
I get the error below when i write the command sudo apt update in my terminal.

I tried these commands
sudo dpkg -i cloudflared-linux-amd64.deb
curl -fsSL https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/pubkey.gpg | sudo gpg --yes --dearmor --output /usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg

echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/ jammy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-client.list sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cloudflare-warp

but the problem still persists, before the error was something else:
https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease:  
The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/coral-edgetpu.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.  
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages'  
 as repository 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

which resulted in me deleting and reinstalling the coral-edgetou.gpg in my sources list, but then the issue changed from that to Cloudfare.
I tried following these instructions as well, but none of the solutions worked.

Take a look at the answers of the following question https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey Search for 22.04 for the latest(?) version of the solution. So far I can't find anything for 24.04 but I am still looking. Note: it reports apt-key is now depreciated.

Note the issue you're having is with a google packages cloud issue not the Cloudflare stuff.
